# XSL: How to concat additional string when setting a HTML table class

Tags: html, xslt

Is there a way to concat some name to a class with a variable?

```
<table style="display:none;border-style:solid;">
     <xsl:attribute name="class">
         <xsl:value-of select="BookName"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
```

This piece of my code would name a class by a value of "BookName" from XML, but I need somehow to concat it with just a static text "booktable", meaning that BookName would be some value, but booktable is always static text for example result would be **class="NewEncouters2009 booktable"**

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
<table style="display:none;border-style:solid;" class="{BookName} booktable">
```

As for `xsl:attribute`, you can of course put in any static text there e.g.

```
<xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="BookName"/> booktable</xsl:attribute>
```